# How to add Contact Form 7 fields to my custom HTML code like the screenshot below?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to create the same of that html style with wordpress contact form 7 , i just need to make that design work functional with wcf 7
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4IhS.png)

and my example html code :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Destination(s)</label>
    <ul class="tags">Fes</ul>
    <ul class="tags">Hight Atlas Mountains</ul>
    <ul class="tags">Marrakech</ul>
    <div class="destinations-wrap">
        <input type="text" class="form-control icon icon-location" name="locations_search" placeholder="e.g. Iceland"
            autocomplete="false">
        <input type="text" class="destinations-suggestion" disabled>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary destinations-wrap-btn" tabindex="-1">+ Add Another</button>
</div>
```

Comment: share ur html code here if u tried.?

Comment: i just add my code @KiranMistry

Comment: Hello again Yassine. You asked similar question about 10 days ago and got two answers, (one of them mine) & one which you accepted >>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58422462/how-to-add-contact-form-7-fields-to-my-custom-html-code _ Did those solutions not work out for you? #JustCurious

Comment: Hello @inputforcolor, they works perfectly , but i this case i don't know how to create  a text as a tag label when i click on button "add another+"

Comment: Do you just want the design of the button? Or are you looking for the functionality (javascript) so that when the button is clicked the form adds another tab? It would be a good idea to add the answer to my question into your question post ; )

Comment: okey i will, i need make that design work with wordpress contact form 7 fields

Answer (score 1):

[This my example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEVqR.png)

You can use only html, and pure javascript. Bellow My Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="foundlose/vendor/meotip/style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">

*{
    font-family: "Raleway";
}
span{
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    background-color: #E13547;
    color:#FAFAFA;
    font-weight: bold;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#destination-list{
    padding: 5px;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="indef">
        <h1>Travel Information</h1>
        <h6>Destiantion(s)</h6>
    </div>
    <div id="destination-list">

    </div>
    <div class="indef">
        <input type="text" name="" id="destination-input">
    </div>
    <div class="indef">
        <button id="add">Add</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var destinationList = document.getElementById('destination-list'),

    destinationInput = document.getElementById('destination-input'),

    add = document.getElementById('add');

    add.onclick = function(){

        var addInput = document.createElement('span'), list = destinationList.getElementsByTagName('span');

        addInput.setAttribute("class",destinationInput.value);

        addInput.textContent = destinationInput.value + " ❌";

        destinationList.appendChild(addInput);

        for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){

            list[i].onclick = function(){

                this.parentNode.removeChild(this);

            }

        }

    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank u but i can't see contact form 7 shortcode fields or they included on javascript code ?

Comment: No, it separated from javascript code. did you mean wordpress plugins?

Comment: I'm Kidding :D. I think, it's a bit difficult to mix pure code with plugins, you may add static page and then paste the code, for other theme's u can use bootstrap template.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your Solution with bootstrap 4

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
      <h4>
      Travel Information
      </h4>
      <br>
      <h6>
      Destination(s)
      </h6>

      <span class="badge badge-secondary">New <i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
      <span class="badge badge-secondary">High Atlas Mountains <i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
      <span class="badge badge-secondary">Marrakesh <i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
      <span class="badge badge-secondary">Moroccan Sahara <i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
      <span class="badge badge-secondary">Morocco <i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>


      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
        <br>

       <div class="search">
        <span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="e.g Iceland" class="form-control">
      </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
        <br>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-orange">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            Add Another
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.badge-secondary{
  border-radius: 0px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.form-control{
  border-radius: 0px;
  height: 50px
}

.btn-orange{
  background-color: #d17841;
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: white;
}


.search { position: relative; }
.search input { text-indent: 30px;}
.search .fa-map-marker { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #8e8e8e;
}
```

You Can Edit or Preview Code Here [On JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7tnbfujx/2/)

Comment: Thank u but i can't see contact form 7 shortcode fields ?